# Get root data of smart contract

Tags: events, logs, state-trie

I am deploying a Smart contract with set of fields.
Updating some fields using events.Till here is fine.

Now here i need to fetch the root data(data while deploying the contract)

Please suggest.

Thanks
Veera

Comment: Can you explain what is root data? Can you give an example?

Comment: Root data means data inserted while creating the contract.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1061.  From a contract you cannot access the previous state of a variable, you have to explicitely track the variable changes in a mapping for example.

Comment: Thanks Ismael.                 How to update and trigger the event with **dynamic input parameters ** in solidity

How to track the smart contract data changes with the time stamp

Please suggest.

Thanks Veera

Comment: Check the solidity documentation about [events](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/structure-of-a-contract.html#structure-events), if you have more doubts try asking a new question.

Comment: Raised here. 
 https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33732/smart-contract-data-update-in-solidity-with-dynamic-input-parameters?noredirect=1#comment36501_33732